# Angular - delete $scope.categoria_nova;

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, delete

O meu delete não funciona quando cadastro uma categoria nova:

O fomulário não limpa os campos, o que pode ser?

JS:

```
app.controller('categoriasCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.categorias = [
    {id: 10, nome: 'Categoria teste 2', ativo: 1},
    {id: 11, nome: 'Categoria teste 3', ativo: 0},
    {id: 12, nome: 'Categoria teste 4', ativo: 1}
    ];
$scope.addCategoria = function (a){
    $scope.categorias.push(a);
    delete $scope.categoria_nova;
};
```

HTML

```html
<form name="categoriaForm">
   <md-content md-theme="docs-dark" layout-padding="" layout="row" layout-sm="column">    
       <md-input-container>        
         <label>Nome</label>
         <input name="nome" ng-model="categoria_nova.nome">
       </md-input-container>
       <div class="checkbox">
        <md-checkbox name="ativo" ng-model="categoria_nova.ativo" aria-label="Ativo">       
           </md-checkbox> 
        <md-tooltip md-direction="top">
      Ativa
     </md-tooltip>
       </div>    
       <md-button class="md-warn md-raised cadastrar" ng-click="addCategoria(categoria_nova)">
        Cadastrar
       </md-button>
   </md-content>
  </form>
</div>
{{categorias}}
<table class="table table-striped table_lista">
     <thead>
     <tr>
      <th class="">      
       <a href="" ng-click="ordenarPor('id')">
        <span class="direction glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes{{directionid}}" aria-hidden="true"></span>#
     </a>
       </th>      
      <th>
       <a  href="" ng-click="ordenarPor('nome')">
        <span class="direction glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet{{directionnome}}" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        Nome
     </a>
    </th>
    <th>Ativa</th>
      <th>Ações</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="categoria in categorias | orderBy:criterioDeOrdenacao:direcaoDaOrdenacao">

     <tr>
      <td>
       {{categoria.id}}
      </td>      
      <td>
       {{categoria.nome}}
      </td>
      <td>
       <span ng-if="categoria.ativo == 1">
      <span class="ativo glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     </span>
      </td>
      <td>
       <md-button class="md-icon-button md-primary" aria-label="Settings">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </md-button>
        <md-button class="md-icon-button md-accent" aria-label="Settings">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </md-button>
      </td>      
     </tr>
     
     
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opa, olá!

Reconstruí seu código e coloquei ele pra funcionar.

Dá uma olhada nesse [Plunker funcionando](http://plnkr.co/edit/UHfjZ3MndRfIsYKW1ql4?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('appBonito', []);

app.controller('categoriasCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.categorias = [
    {id: 10, nome: 'Categoria teste 2', ativo: 1},
    {id: 11, nome: 'Categoria teste 3', ativo: 0},
    {id: 12, nome: 'Categoria teste 4', ativo: 1}
    ];


$scope.addCategoria = function (a){
    $scope.categorias.push(a);
    delete $scope.categoria_nova;
}
});
```

Não alterei muita coisa, só fiz adicionar o necessário pra funcionar. No caso, ng-app, ng-controller e instanciar o módulo appBonito. A função addCategoria estava incompleta, mas provavelmente porque você esqueceu de colar o fechamento do controller. Então, dá uma olhada e corrige baseado nesse código.

Algo importante a perceber é a [terrível eficiência do delete](https://jsperf.com/delete-vs-undefined-vs-null/3). Sendo aconselhado, portanto, utilizar uma das soluções abaixo ou apresentadas no link:

- $scope.categoria_nova = undefined = null;
- $scope.categoria_nova = {};

Comment: Show, muito obrigado.

Comment: @user3801617 , você pode marcar a resposta que melhor solucionar seu problema como 'Melhor resposta' depois que tiver terminado. :)

Answer (score 0):

Quando sua tela renderiza, o angular entende que ela faz referência a variável `$scope.categoria_nova` que não foi instanciada no controlador, sendo assim ele a instancia automaticamente.

Quando você executa o código `delete $scope.categoria_nova` você está apenas apagando a variável do escopo, sem prover algo que o angular possa fazer binding para a tela, assim a tela não tem como se atualizar.

Uma solução simples é fazer o seguinte `$scope.categoria_nova = {};`

Comment: Muito obrigado, eu tinha feito com [] em vez de {} ai a minha array se perdia.

Comment: @Ricardo, do ponto de vista teórico, por que [esse código](http://plnkr.co/edit/UHfjZ3MndRfIsYKW1ql4?p=preview) funcionou se estou usando o delete do jeito que você disse que não iria?

Comment: @Rodmentou, provavelmente porquê estou errado em minha afirmação, eu tinha certeza sobre ela até que você provou o contrário.

Comment: Não era intenção te provar errado, só que eu fiquei em dúvida porque o que você falou tem fundamento. :p

Comment: Mesmo não querendo provar, provou, hehe, o angular tem alguns vários problemas de não detectar coisas alterações que foram feitos "por fora" do escopo, achei que o delete se encaixava nesta situação quando o bean raiz era alterado, mas aparentemente não.